# Adding Edge to Janusgraph via Gremlin interface

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Can anyone explain why this doesn't seem to do anything

```
ve = g.addV("test").as("m").iterate()
g.addV("test2").as("q").V(ve).addE("contains").from("q").iterate()
g.V().hasLabel("test2").outE().otherV().path()
```

The operation executes without error but then doesn't return anything when asking for the edges.

I know I could join the traversals together, but I'm specifically looking at a usecase where I'd create the first vertex in a slightly different block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
ve = g.addV("test").as("m").iterate()
```

should be

```
ve = g.addV("test").as("m").next()
```

Comment: You got it http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/gremlin.html#_iterating_the_traversal